# combine jquery in php for displaying a collapsible list fetched from database

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

The following program is supposed to display the subjects and subcategory in collapsible list order.

But the collapsible list is applied for the first entry only. The rest of the items appear static. They dont collapse. **Why??????????**

```
<html><head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");
$sql="select * from subject";
$res_subject=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res_subject))
{
?>

<UL id="subj_tree">
    <LI><span> <?php  echo $row['sub_name'];?> </span>
        <UL>
        <?php
        $sql="select * from sub_categry where sub_id=".$row['sub_id'];
        $res_sub_cat=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
        while($val=mysqli_fetch_array($res_sub_cat))
        {       
        ?>   <LI><span> <?php echo $val['sub_cat_name']; ?> </span></LI>

        <?php } ?>
    </UL>

</LI>
</UL>
<?php
}
?>
 </html>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function(){
      $('#subj_tree').find('UL').hide();
      $('#subj_tree').find('SPAN').click(function(e){
        $(this).parent().children('UL').toggle();

  });

  });
```

mysql db is like as follow:

sub_categry: `sub_cat_id`, `sub_cat_type`, `sub_id` (foreign key `subject.sub_id`)
subject: `sub_id`, `sub_name`.

Comment: Am I the only one wondering why you are capitalising your `<ul>` and `<li>`, and why you are using such wildly inefficient code? Why not just use `$('#subj_tree li ul`')` or `$('#subj_tree ul span')` as selectors? Now you're just throwing a find function (very inefficient) over something that gives it no gains. Selector nesting is way more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery find() method only gives you the first element that matches the selector. If you want *all* the  tags under #subj_tree to be hidden, you would have to use

```
$('#subj_tree ul').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't trigger a click using `find()` function. You should use this function instead:

```
$('#subj_tree > li > span').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().children('UL').toggle();
});
```

Comment: I can't comment others posts so in reply to seven77: according to jQuery's documentation, _.find(): Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element._

Answer (score 0):

It's because your structure is completely wrong. Your code is also wildly inefficient. Also, you are including jquery twice. That probably doesn't do much good!

Your script tag also isn't closed and it should be included within the body.(something you are also missing)
Can you try it like this?:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <style>#subj_tree ul {display: none;}</style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php
      $con         = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");
      $sql         = "select * from subject";
      $res_subject = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

      while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($res_subject) ) {
    ?>

        <ul id="subj_tree">
          <li><span> <?php echo $row['sub_name']; ?> </span>
               <ul>
          <?php
            $sql         = "select * from sub_categry where sub_id=" . $row['sub_id'];
            $res_sub_cat = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
            while( $val = mysqli_fetch_array($res_sub_cat) ) {
          ?>
                 <li><span> <?php echo $val['sub_cat_name']; ?> </span></li>

            <?php } ?>
               </ul>

          </li>
         </ul>
    <?php
  }
?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function () {
        $('#subj_tree > li span').on("click", function (e) {
          var parent = $(this).parent();
          $('ul', parent).toggle();
        });
      });
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

see this JSFiddle for a working example;
https://jsfiddle.net/qum571nn/