# Collapsible list: changed behaviour on first click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-lists

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39064885/combine-jquery-in-php-for-displaying-a-collapsible-list-fetched-from-database) answer and [this](https://jsfiddle.net/qum571nn/) code example while looking for a collapsible HTML list.
After adding a few more sublevels, my code now looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <style>
    #subj_tree ul{
      display:none;
    }
    </style> 
  </head>
<body>

<ul id="subj_tree">
    <li><span>sub name</span>
        <ul>
         <li><span> sub2* cat name</span>
            <ul>
                <li><span> sub3* cat name </span>
                    <ul>
                       <li><span> sub4 cat name </span></li>
                       <li><span> sub4 cat name </span></li>
                       <li><span> sub4 cat name </span></li>
                     </ul> 
                </li>    
                <li><span> sub3 cat name </span></li>
                <li><span> sub3 cat name </span></li>
                <li><span> sub3 cat name </span></li>
             </ul>         
         </li>
         <li><span> sub2 cat name </span></li>
         <li><span> sub2 cat name </span></li>
         <li><span> sub2 cat name </span></li>
         <li><span> sub2 cat name </span></li>
       </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<script>
  $(function () {
    $('#subj_tree > li span').on("click", function (e) {
      var parent = $(this).parent();
      $('ul', parent).toggle();
    });
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The first click on "sub name" automatically expands all underlying levels (sub2 + sub3) in this case, which is not what I want. 
I would prefer if only the next sub level (#2 in my code) was expanded initially, letting me manually expand level #3 (and perhaps levels #4, #5...) if needed.
How do I accomplish this?